# When frictional force is always acting on rear wheel of cycle how maintaing of constant speed is possible?(neglect drag)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

When frictional force always act on the rear wheel of the cycle when pedaling with constant force,how maintaining of Cycle speed constant at low speeds.(i mean if you push the pedal with certain force why it moves with constant speed instead of accelerating?)(imagine cycle is at low speeds).

Comment: Why doesn't it go forever when you spin it once?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you answered your own question.. the constant frictional force, if equal to the applied force provided through pedaling, will result in a constant velocity.

To go from rest to this velocity, you must accelerate, however (think Newton's second law), meaning the applied force was greater than the frictional force.

Also, you should keep in mind what's really happening when you pedal. You apply a force on the pedals, which then exerts a net torque on a gear. This gear is attached to a chain, which causes the gears connected to the wheel to turn when you push the pedals. Depending on the moment arm of the back gear, different mechanical advantages are achieved based on the principle of an equal force with a greater radius exerting a greater net torque.